# How to programmatically disable a category?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, category, category-attribute

```
$category_id = 8711;
$cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id);
$cat->setData('is_active', 0);
$cat->save();
```

it does not work...

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is okay, but if it's a standalone script that just uses `Mage::app();` at the beginning, it will not work, but it does if you set a store ID via `setCurrentStore(store_id)`

To change the default value, you can use

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
# your code here
```

Comment: it worked:     Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));

Comment: @Majör this `load(...)` isnt necessary. `setCurrentStoreId(...)` should be enough (at least it worked for me). Please accept, answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recon your code should work but if it does not, try this:

```
$category_id = 8711;
$cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id);
$cat->setIsActive(0);
$cat->save()
```